# Using the fundamental theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a couple of questions. I have them answered mostly I think, but I haven't done these before so hoping for some confirmation that I am right.

The question is to use the fundamental thm of calculus to find $F'(x)$ if

$(1) F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^2} dt$

To which my answer is $F'(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2}$ ?

$(2) F(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t} dt.$

Is this question written wrong in the notes, as it has two dts?

$(3) \int_{1}^{2x}\cos(t^2) dt.$
 I used the chain rule and got $2\cos(4x^2) ?$

Thank you for any help provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in every case. In particular, yes, the double $\mathrm dt$ is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Your answer is right.

(2) Yes, the question is written wrong.

(3) Your answer is right.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If you find out, don't forget to tell me. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, was that not an upvote I gave? I clicked the 'up' arrow? When I hover my mouse over it it says 'this answer was useful' so I clicked it?

Comment: @moony Someone downvoted the question and both answers. I suspect that it was the same person, thinking that the question did not deserve to be here and that those who answered it should be punished for that.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I dislike when people do that (especially since I didn't jut ask a question without any work done), I am trying to learn and it may be trivial to some people but I haven't done it before. Thank you for taking the time to answer.